# tmux how to scroll two pane like vim scrollbind

Tags: file, scroll, tmux, pane

How to scroll two pane side by side like vim.

In vim I can use scrollbind to scroll two file side by side.

For example:
Open the first file with `vim LICENSE`

Open another file with `:set vsplit LICENSE`

Bind the first file with `:set scrollbind`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> switch to another file and bind it with `:set scrollbind` (Unbind is  `:set noscrollbind`)

Then I can scroll the two file with up and down key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it does not limit to scroll, but you can use `:setw synchronize-panes` in tmux.

http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#synchronize-panes

**UPDATE: THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK FOR SCROLLING ANYMORE!**

Comment: Great, works well.  And  `:setw synchronize-panes` is a toggle command here. So use the same command to turn it off.

Comment: yep, or you can specify your target state: `:setw synchronize-panes on` or  `:setw synchronize-panes off`

Comment: This doesn't seem to synchronize scrolling for me. As soon as I do `prefix+[` the synchronization is off.

Comment: @doktor-oswaldo How do you scroll? With synchronization on I can type and everything ends up in all panes, but when I try to scroll, tmux enters copy mode and scrolls for the currently focused pane but not the others. I also have to exit copy mode for each pane individually.

Comment: @SebastianBlask the command just sends your keyboard input to all panes. I don't know how you scroll or how your tmux is configured but it should just react the same, as if you enter the input in all panes one after the other.

Comment: @doktor-oswaldo I know what it does, that's why I wonder how you trigger scrolling in all panes. When I use `ctrl-b [` tmux enters copy mode for the currently focused pane and that pane is no longer part of the synchronisation.

Comment: @SebastianBlask I usually use `set -g mouse on`  for scrolling, but you are indeed right, this answer does not seem to work anymore! But the synchronization is not off for me, it does just not work with scrolling. If you exit copy mode, is the sync really off?

Comment: @doktor-oswaldo No, after I exit copy mode sync is working again.